# A missing 'let' keyword changes the flow of program

Tags: javascript

The first prompt of the following program asks for `name = prompt("Who's there","");`. If i press `esc` or `cancel` the prompt variable `name` should be `null` (it is null i checked in Mozilla's watch expression) and hence should execute the `else if (name == '' || name == null)` and alert the user as `Canceled`. But the program skips the above said `else if` and executes the last `else` there by showing `"I don't know you"`. If i change variable declaration to include keyword `let` and modify code as `let name = prompt("Who's there","");` it works as it should and on pressing `esc` or `cancel` of first prompt it displays `Canceled`.

What changes when i do not declare a variable using `let`?

code:

```js
login();

function login(){
    name = prompt("Who's there","");
    if (name == 'Admin')
    {
        password = prompt("Password?","");
        if (password == 'TheMaster')
        {
            alert("Welcome!");
        }
        else if (password == '' || password == null)
        {
            alert("Canceled");
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Wrong password');
        }
    }
    else if (name == '' || name == null) 
    {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("I don't know you");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Login example with JS</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../HTML/scripts/login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login Page using prompt</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you check for null with isnull() funciton - or something like that

Comment: Gloabl `name` can't be `null`, since it's a "type-protected" property of `window` (always a string).

Comment: Without `let` (or `var`), the variable is an "implicit global". In this particular case, it's especially bad: browsers have a global variable `name` that reflects the name of the window. **Always declare variables explicitly with `let` or `const`.**

Comment: More about implicit globals on my old anemic blog: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Using `let` means you're shadowing the automatic `name` global that comes from the `window `object.

Comment: "_(it is null i checked in Mozilla's watch expression)_" Take a careful look at the value, it's not `null`, rather it's `"null"`.

Comment: @Teemu so as you said Gloabl name can't be null, since it's a "type-protected" property of window (always a string). "null" is a string and not a type- null.?

Comment: Yep, you can check this quickly on the console, just write `name = null` and hit enter, the console responses with a string "null". `window.name` property is actually a getter/setter pair, and the setter makes a type coercion before storing the value internally.